# Android PrefernceFragment implements OnPreferenceClickListener never invoked on clicks

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, onpreferenceclicklistener

I'm trying to implement `OnPreferenceClickListener` over `PrefernceFragment` and it seems like the `onPreferenceClick()` is never called.
I have another `PrefernceFragment` implementing `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and it works just fine.
Is this a bug of the OS ? is the `OnPreferenceClickListener` not supposed to be supported for `PrefernceFragment` ?
If there is no need to register the fragment as listener as I read, then I really think my code is correct.

```
    public class myClass extends PreferenceFragment implements OnPreferenceClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(com.XX.ZZ.R.xml.YY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        // never called.
    }
}
```

Comment: posting some code shouldn't be so hard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PreferenceFragment` doesn't have a `onPreferenceClick()` method. There is really no need to listen for click events since the Android fragment takes care of writing the preference values into memory. If you really need to watch for a click event, you can use `findPreference(CharSequence key)` to find each of the `Preference`s you want to watch and then call `setOnPreferenceClickListener(this)` on those.

Comment: I'm aware of the ability to manually register listener per preference.  Too bad the listener can't be implemented.

Comment: It is unfortunate, but this is the only way to do it with a `PreferenceFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

You must set preferenceClickListener on your preference.

```
public class myClass extends PreferenceFragment implements OnPreferenceClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(com.XX.ZZ.R.xml.YY);
        Preference preference = findPreference("myPreference");
        preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        // never called.
    }
```

UPDATE:

If you want to set onPreferenceClickListener to all preferences, you can do it like this:

```
public class myClass extends PreferenceFragment implements OnPreferenceClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.menu.main);

        Set<String> preferenceNames = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().getAll().keySet();
        for (String prefName : preferenceNames) {
            Preference preference = findPreference(prefName);
            preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        // or get preference.getKey() to select based on preference names
        switch (preference.getOrder()) {
        case 0:

            return true;
        case 1:

            return true;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is specific per preference, The implementation of the click listener has no extra value on this case, the idea was to get the listener callback without per-preference registration.